# How to select a dataframe column based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a condition based on each value unique of a data frame column using python .

I tried to put it in a list and iterate to take all the value :

```
**f=(df['Technical family'].unique())
for i in f:
    df_2 = df[(df['Technical family'] = f[i])]
    S=pd.crosstab(df_2['PFG | ID'],df_2['Comp. | Family'])

    **
```

but apparently  the `df_2 = df[(df['Technical family'] = f[i])]` doesn't work !
Anyone have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `==` instead of `=`. `==` is for comparing values while `=` is for assigning values.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Technical family':np.random.choice(['1','2','3'],100),
                   'PFG | ID':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],100),
                   'Comp. | Family':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'],100)})

f=(df['Technical family'].unique())
df_2 = df[df['Technical family']==f[0]]
pd.crosstab(df_2['PFG | ID'],df_2['Comp. | Family'])


Comp. | Family  a   b   c
PFG | ID            
A   5   5   3
B   3   5   3
C   4   3   4
```

Also as a further suggestion, you can directly crosstab:

```
res = pd.crosstab([df['Technical family'],df['PFG | ID']],df['Comp. | Family'])
res.loc['1']
```

Comment: i tried == , i think the problem was in the loop not the asign !  Thank you

Comment: Yes.. you are not storing the crosstab results anywhere. Can you try what I suggested in the last part?